# Change current build system shortcut

Tags: sublimetext2

Can I switch between build systems using shortcut?

I've created a few build systems to execute sql on different databases - stagings, devs etc. 
I googled it but can't find how can I switch between build systems with shortcut or so, cause switching between them using mouse(Tools->Build System-> check build system) is quite slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making them completely different build systems, use **variants** ([documented here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#variants)). For instance, you could have a custom build file that looked a bit like this:

```
{
  "name": "sql dev"
  "cmd": [<command to execute on development server>]
  "selector": "source.sql",

  "variants":
    [
      {
    "name": "sql staging",
    "cmd": [<command to execute in staging area>]
      },
      {
    "name": "sql production",
    "cmd": [<command to execute on production server>]
      }
    ]
}
```

When this build file is active/selected, the build command will execute `sql dev`.  <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (Windows/Linux) will execute `sql staging`.  You can access all three through the command palette; just search for "build."